# AVPlayer is not playing a locally saved video file

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I have this code attempting to play a previously saved file (which exists) but I see a black screen while playing the video.

```
static func playVideo(from filename: String, vc: UIViewController, view: UIView) -> Bool {
    let filepath = videosDirectoryPath + filename
    if (MediaUtils.fileExists(filePath: filepath)) {
        Logging.logError("Playing video failed, file not found: \(filepath)")
        return false
    }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath))
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    playerViewController.view.frame = view.frame
    view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
    vc.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
    return true
}
```

I do see an error `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <AVPlayerViewController: 0x109010e00>.` but not sure if that has anything to do here. I am able to play a URL fine with this:

```
static func playVideo(videoUrl: String, vc: UIViewController, view: UIView) {
    Logging.logDebug("Playing video \(videoUrl)")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: videoUrl)!)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    playerViewController.view.frame = view.frame
    view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
    vc.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Any idea why the locally saved file cannot be played. Wish there is an error from `player.play()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a shot

```
func playVideo(videoUrl: String, vc: UIViewController, view: UIView) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoUrl) as URL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    playerLayer.frame = logoImageView.frame
    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    vc.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        player?.play()
    }
}
```